# How to check syntax error on algebraic expression

Tags: java, syntax, algebra

I've been searching for a method to only check if an algebraic expression is well written, but I only find "how to solve this thing" or "how to simplify like Mathematica".

You'll see, I have a program with a field to input a String, the string should be something like

> "(x-a)^2-y+2"

, and I have to check if it's correct, so if the user inputs something like:

- ")x-4(+1"
- "x*"
- "4-9)6"
- "+*--*7"
  ...etc, I have to say that it's wrong and try again. I don't need a result, or to evaluate on x or anything, just that. Does anyone knows how to do this?
  I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica, wxMaxima, Maple, etc. use a syntax tree. They define a grammar and parse the expression using that grammar. Furthermore sometimes some type checking is done.

One can generate a Java-parser using Yacc or Bison.